# How to click this element with value 50 , i'm using casper for this this to select

Tags: javascript, php, html, casperjs

[Location of the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0dGR.jpg)

> The three Dropdown Options
>   [image]

This is how it works in a web page to `select value 50:` I'm clicking the dropdown bar and then there `three values are shown 10, 20 and 50` and when I click on `50 the page refreshes and 50 data's are shown in 1 page`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] (a picture of your code does not count as code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`casper.click()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click) with an [XPath expression](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html#index-2) to click on an element by text content.

**The XPath expression you can use in your case is:**

```
//div[@id="dnn_ctr1000_MainView_rgMain_ct100_ct103_ct101_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div[@class="rcbScroll rcbWidth"]/ul[@class="rcbList"]/li[text()="50"]
```

**Using CasperJS, you can write the full program:**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('https://example.com/');

casper.then(function () {
  this.click(x('//div[@id="dnn_ctr1000_MainView_rgMain_ct100_ct103_ct101_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div[@class="rcbScroll rcbWidth"]/ul[@class="rcbList"]/li[text()="50"]'));
});

casper.run();
```

This will allow you to simulate a click event on the element that contains the text content `50`.